# Overriding an External Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I'm currently using Bootstrap 3 to create a web page that has styling I would like to modify. I have both the bootstrap css and my custom css properly linked to the web page, and because I linked the latter stylesheet after the former, I was hoping my custom external stylesheet would override the Bootstrap styles that I wanted to change.

Needless to say, it didn't work. A lot of embedded style looks gross, and I don't want to make **any** changes to the Bootstrap css, so I was wondering if any of you knew some nifty ways to get one external css file to override another.

(Already tried giving it a specific id too, to no avail).

Comment: You need to include the second stylesheet after you include the first one. You can also use more highly-prioritized selectors

Comment: Probably find this useful: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ - simply assigning an ID isn't guaranteed to make the selector more specific than the Bootstrap rules.

Answer (score 5):

CSS reads top-down, therefore anything lower in the code will overwrite anything already seen.

If something isn't taking effect it's because there's some other code overriding it. Use an element inspector such as Webkit Dev Tools or Firebug to see what styles are being applied and how.

`!important is also needed to override anything marked as !important in the "higher" css file` (via @BFDatabaseAdmin)

Read: [When Using !important is The Right Choice](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: Shouldn't that be "anything higher in the code should be overwritten" or "anything lower in the code will overwrite anything already seen" (your text appears to contradict the top --> bottom nature of css)

Comment: !important is also needed to override anything marked as !important in the "higher" css file.

Answer (score 0):

1. May be Your custom external style sheet was not linked properly. Check for any 404 status on your custom style sheet.
2. Make sure you have not misspelled anything
3. Possible solution would be to add !important at the end of properties.
   .alert-info {
       background-color : #4D98D2 !important;
   }